# programatically change customer password in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, password, change-password

How can i programatically  change customer password in magento 2?
can anyone please help me to solve this

Comment: Any code you have developed?

Comment: currently no code..

Comment: Duplicate of [Magento 2 - Change customer password programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105175/magento-2-change-customer-password-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository` has an extra argument passwordHash

Use this argument to set a new password:

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
$this->customerRepository->save($customer, $this->encryptor->getHash($password, true));
```

Comment: @ i have used the above code but the password is not changing

Comment: what issue generated?

Comment: how to define encryptor because i am getting error

Comment: @RohanHapani, will it work if we load customer object with customerFactory ?